# Should I use SQL Server DMVs with NOLOCK

Tags: sql-server, performance, dmv, performance-tuning

I am trying to monitor live performance data and usage, which cannot be tracked with PerformanceMonitor. What are the consequences of reading DMVs in a production live OLTP database? : Eg: sys.dm_tran_locks, sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks, sys.dm_os_performance_counters, sys.dm_exec_connections, sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats,  sys.dm_exec_sql_text,etc

Should I just utilize WITH (NOLOCK) when querying Dmvs? Would this resolve many of the resource issues? Is there anything such as dirty read rollbacks in DMVs. I know it can exist in applications tables eg where someone submits an order then cancels, etc. Additionally, with NOLOCK, is there higher chance query will continue forever in high volume environment since I am not locking rows, pages, and things will continue be added into DMV TableView?

Thank you,

Comment: Please see my answer to "[Does querying the sys entities and DMVs lock the underlying tables and what happens when SQL Server tries to write to them?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/253442/30859)" (also here on DBA.SE) for additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the consequences of reading DMVs in a production live OLTP database?

Negligible as far as my experience goes. DMV's as the name suggests are basically views or functions ( like sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats ) which get information from various caches and system tables. DMV's are very light and read data from caches. They do not cause blocking and depending on amount of data you need to fetch they very very quick. The point here is always only query data from caches which you actually need.

You may use NOLOCK hint in your DMV query you would see some people using it but frankly I do not see much of need to use it with DMV's. Its function though still remains same. So when you use NOLOCK hint you say to SQL Server that give me the data I am asking no matter what is state of the data is. It may have been changed and yet not committed so you get "dirty" data. NOLOCK hint avoids select queries taking shared lock while reading data. The drawbacks are [many](https://www.izenda.com/blog/high-performance-sql-views-using-withnolock/)

> Additionally, with NOLOCK, is there higher chance query will continue forever in high volume environment since I am not locking rows, pages, and things will continue be added into DMV TableView?

Query will only continue for duration until it finishes its task, unless you run a never ending loop. The NOLOCK only ensures that query is minimally blocked and also note that when using NOLOCK if required other locks like schema stability  are taken

Comment: so there is a chance, DMV data may have been changed and yet not committed so you get "dirty" data, do you know this for sure? Would Microsoft know?

Comment: @AppleBook89 You may get dirty data there is no guarantee. I have not tested how NOLOCK works with DMV's though. There are times when load on server is negligible and nothing much is changing and you are more concerned about output than the accurateness in that case you may use NOLOCK hint.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article whilst researching blocking on using DMV during system upgrades.

Consider:

```
alter table X Add (y bit)
```

This will take a SCH_M lock on table X (and remain until transaction is committed/rolled back)

if you try and run

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_query_stats
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
```

You will be blocked until the previous transaction completes. NOLOCK won't help you here, because the locked being taken is a SCH_S which you cannot avoid.